# Authentication on specific method for generic API views

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have used `ListCreateAPIView` and `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` for a model. Now I want to add **JWT** authentication to only the **Update and Destroy** part in the `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`. How can I do that?

---

Let me make my question a bit more clear. I have a model named `Post`. Now All users are allowed to **view** the post but **update, delete** is only available to the user who created it. And I want to use **JWT Authentication**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write [custom permission](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) class for this:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class CustomPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if view.action in ('update', 'destroy'):
            return request.user.is_authenticated
        return True
```

And use in in your view:

```
class ExampleView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = (CustomPermission,)
```

Comment: Will this work for the update that i made in question?

Answer (score 0):

we can override the method  `get_authenticators` and don't forget to add `authentication_classes` to api view.

```
def get_authenticators(self):
    if self.request.method in ['PUT', 'DELETE']:
        return [auth() for auth in self.authentication_classes]
    else:
        return []
```

For your question update we need to add object level permissions like below

```
class OwnerRequiredPermission(object):

     def has_object_permission(self, request, obj):
          return obj.created_by == request.user
```

add above permission class to `permission_classes`

Comment: Will this work for the update that i made in question?